# Question closed as duplicate that's clearly not a duplicate

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-closed

I'd like to understand why this question

[Extract Heading from Word to Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50838029/extract-heading-from-word-to-excel/50838427#50838427)

Has been closed as a duplicate, linking to [transfer data from word to excel via vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41011932/transfer-data-from-word-to-excel-via-vba)

The OP in the closed question is specifically asking about how to get a Word heading level preceding a specific range (Comment). This is *not* the topic of the supposed duplicate. It's not mentioned and not one of the answers goes into it.

IMO the question should not have been closed.

Edit: It's been re-opened. Thanks to all who read the thread and gave the topic due consideration!

Comment: The OP agreed it was a duplicate, hence the "Community" vote, so... It would seem _they_ feel their question was answered by the other post.

Comment: Where do you see that? I see no discussion about duplication in the post or comments? Are we seeing the same thing?

Comment: _marked as duplicate by Vityata, **Community♦** XX mins ago_

Comment: When there is a duplicate flag on a question (or vote? not sure), the OP of that question is offered the duplicate, with a "this answered my question" button. If they click "this answered my question", the post is marked as dupe by Community.

Comment: This is more than strange. Firstly, that it was suggested as a duplicate to begin with, as it was clearly. Not. I've rolled back a major content edit done by the OP. This person already accepted and upvoted my answer. I can't understand why they altered / deleted the question content and accepted as a duplicate, nor why this duplicate was even suggested. There's no logic to it.

Comment: The person is new to Stack Overflow (so little rep), so maybe they felt pressured into accepting the strange duplicate suggestion?

Comment: It also looks like they've changed their profile name...

Comment: The duplicate was suggested by a high profile user (25k+) so they probably chose the correct duplicate (The duplicate seem relevant to the original question). The OP didn't change the post completely but they did remove important parts from the question

Comment: It looks a bit like a student-covering-up-their-tracks rollback, which feels odd, as this doesn't look like a typical homework question.

Comment: I think we shouldn't count the OP accepting the dupe, since that happened after the OP deleted nearly all the relevant content. She likely wanted to get rid of the question, and spent 5-6 hours before deciding to accept the dupe. I'm for reopening this one, because the dupe is slapping a general answer on a debugging question with relatively good code: not that helpful unless you also point out what's going wrong.

Comment: @AlonEitan Cindy Meister is #5 in the all-time ranking for [ms-word], so I don't think the "high profile user" bit is relevant here.

Comment: [2/2] Do note, though, that closing this question might not be the worst idea. Since it's a debugging question, future visitors are more likely to be helped by the question it links to, and it won't roomba, so it will still be around, it really doesn't need new answers (which is the only real thing being prevented here), and you won't lose any rep by it getting closed.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth This is not a debugging question - it's a "How do I get the previous Heading level in a Word document" question. Not a simple thing at all if you don't have very in-depth knowledge of Word - from the old WordBasic days. Losing the information in the Answer would be a great loss for the site. Unless someone can find it somewhere else on the site.

Comment: Voted to reopen too then

Comment: @duplode Thank you. The high-rep person who closed is not a Word person. And truly, I think the duplicate vote was probably meant for a different question and put on this one in error. But we'll only know that when / if s/he comes through, here...

Comment: @Cindy It won't really be lost. It will be a bit harder to find for users that aren't logged in. But I see, and  I've put in my reopen vote.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Well, that makes me feel somewhat better :-) I put a lot of heart into researching that and it would be a shame to lose it. It's rare in such a low-traffic tag to get 3 upvotes in less than a day - I treasure the experience and it makes me realize how useful people are finding it, already.

Comment: @Cindy Nothing is lost when a question is closed as a duplicate. In fact something is gained, the links between the topics.

Comment: @davidHefferman Yes, if the link between the topics were meaningful I could follow the reasoning. But in this case it's not so - there's simply no correlation in the content beyond the fact that both deal with extracting information to pass to Excel. But what should be extracted from Word and how it's done... it's like comparing apples with oranges. Both are called fruit, and you can eat them, but they're not the same.

Comment: @CindyMeister I remember seeing this yesterday - it looked like OP had  voted to close their own question as a duplicate... which had me asking myself, why is there even the option to do such a thing for your own question???

Comment: And in the meantime, the user has apparently deleted itself from the site (or management did so), costing me rep.... <sigh> As to your remark, @dwirony: in an ideal world it makes sense, if the OP hadn't realized the question had already been answered. I have no problem with the capability. But it appears those who speculate in comments that the person was trying to "cover up" were correct.